# Google Cloud Redis - IP Address changed without warning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, celery, django-celery, google-cloud-memorystore

TLDR: I could use some advice on how to setup Redis for production use on GPC, it just switched IP addresses on us randomly, and there is nothing in the documentation about that / I have no idea how to build a stable solution with that possibility.

Background:

We've been using google cloud for a few years and had a stable Redis Memorystore instance on the 'Standard' Tier.

In the past few days, our web servers started slowly crashing every so often. After investigating, something was locking up when connecting to celery / Redis, and we found that all our config files had 10.0.0.3 as the Redis instance, and the IP address for the server was listed as 10.0.0.4. This hasn't changed ever, and our configs are in git so we're sure they were unchanged.

Since Celery won't boot up with a bad connection we know it was correct on Tuesday when we pushed up new code. It seems like the server failed over and somehow issued an IP address change on us. As evidence,

[Our graphical usage bizarrely change color at a specific point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o06zH.png)

Which matches our error logs "[2020-06-16 03:09:21,873: ERROR/MainProcess] Error in timer: ReadOnlyError("You can't write against a read-only slave.",)"

All the documentation we have found says the IP address would stay the same, but given that didn't happen, I'm hoping for some feedback on how one would work around a non-static IP in this case on GPC

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Memorystore does not support static IP address. Some scenarios where IP address change can occur are restarts or when connection modes are changed.

From review of the Memorystore for [Redis networking page](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/networking), when using direct access connection via IP address your project will set up a VPC network peering connection with Google's internal project, where the instance is managed. This will create an allocated IP range for Memorystore to use for the instances, this can either be provided by you or picked from the available space (will be a /29 block by default).

On the other hand, Memorystore for Redis exposes the uptime as a metric that is available through [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/monitoring-instances#monitoring_instances_with) (formally Stackdriver). This can be used as a health check for the instance as you will be able to determine if there has been a restart or points of unavailability.

Following the point above, you are able to set up an alert on the uptime metric directly in [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts). Unfortunately there is nothing specific to IP address changes though.